# lastRecordedPullTime property missing in API_ImageDetail response

Tags: amazon-ecr

I am trying to delete old images from my ECR repositories. I was going to do it by deleting images, that have not been pulled longer than X days.

This API gives https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_ImageDetail.html the `lastRecordedPullTime`. However this property is missing on majority of images (I have hundreds of thousands of images some of them older than 5 years).

I guess this property is missing if image was never pulled, but number of these images is marginal.
My theory would be, that this property is deleted after the some amount of time, during which image was not pulled. If so what is the amount?

Or is there another reason why is `lastRecordedPullTime` property missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the long delay in response. For posterity, I'd like to answer.

This attribute was added to ECR in 2022, and is only added to existing older images if they are pulled. If you have an older image without this attribute, pulling it should add it.